# Как перейти на другую страницу в Selenium после авторизации?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.6

Для авторизации страницы на сайте использую Selenium.

Python код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = 'D:\\temp\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)
browser.get('https://example.com/login/')
email = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
password = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
login = browser.find_element_by_id('submit')
email.send_keys('mymail@mail.ru')
password.send_keys('mypass')
login.click()
browser.get('https://account.example.com/details')
```

После авторизации, переход на новую страницу не происходит. Как можно перейти на:

```
https://account.example.com/details
```

Comment: после клика, попробуйте `time.sleep(10)`

Comment: К сожалению без эффекта.

Comment: ну а в браузере что виднеется? страница открылась? логин и пароль ввелись? кликает по кнопке? капча?

Comment: Логин с паролем вводится. Кнопка нажимается. Происходит переход в личный кабинет. И на этом этапе стопор!